# How to handle moderation of users known personally?

Tags: user-behavior, moderators

I have several co-workers or friends who are active on a site that I moderate, they also know that I'm a moderator.  I've come across a situation where one of these users has been participating in inappropriate behavior directed at other users.

When a moderator has a personal relationship with the user, should you allow another moderator to take action?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> When a moderator has a personal relationship with the user, should you allow another moderator to take action?

Almost always. In fact, *ask* another moderator to take care of it. Business + friends almost always == disaster.

Some things that could go wrong:

- You might not give them enough punishment/be lenient on them.
- They could accuse you of giving them too much of a punishment and say, "I'm nice to you, why do you have to be a jerk?"
- Another member of the community might say that you didn't punish them enough (even if you did).
- It could make other moderators cautions or skeptical, making this entire thing a bigger deal than it needs to be.

I don't see any real advantage to doing this. Just, please, *don't do this*.

Answer (score 10):

**Let someone else do it.**

This is to preserve not only the integrity of the moderation of the site, but the friendships of you and your peers. Don't moderate people you know - if you think something's amiss, pass it off to someone else.